# Black Background instead of transparent screen in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-background, android-14

I have an activity which uses the theme - Theme_Dialog (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style#Theme_Dialog).
I am trying to test my app in the upcoming Android14(A14) Beta build, but the screen (apart from the the activity) is showing as black (in A14 only) while it is transparent in other devices (A13, A12, etc.).
[Expected Output when activity is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q92Vw.jpg)
[Actual output in A14 device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ozg.png)

I have also tried explicitly setting the backgroundDimAmount and backgroundDimEnabled properties but the black background still persists.
While setting the above two properties I noticed that the minor background screen that is visible (white screen in between the black screen and my activity) the color or dimness of that part does change as I change the value for the two properties.
I have also tested it in emulator where it works as expected (the rest of the screen is transparent), but does not work the same way on physical device.